# Zend_Auth::getInstance() fails randomly

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i have a website which runs on zend 2 when i call `Zend_Auth::getInstance();` in an action it works sometimes while on other cases it does not this happens very randomly but it is more likely to fail on a browser that i have just cleared the cookies. Any one who would point me to a probable cause of this behavior is highly appreciated

Comment: Please don't open the same question twice - instead edit your original question to include additional information. The only difference between this and your last question is that this one specifically mentions Zend Framework 2. Yet the class you mention is ZF1 only.